# Group members in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dimensions

Please Consider this table:

```
 Year        Amount
 -------------------
 2010        10000
 2011        12300
 2012        14000
 2013        13000
 2014        22000
 2015        10000
```

I want to create a table in `Power BI` like this:

```
 Year        Amount
 -------------------
 2010        10000
 2011        12300
 2012        14000
 2013        13000
 2014        22000
 2015        10000
 Last2Years  32000
```

I have two questions:

**1)** How can I group two memberss and place it in original dimension?

**2)** Can it be dynamic that group every two last years? For example if 2016 add to dimension then my group is `2015+2016`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAX there is not any way to add a row to an existing table, you must duplicate the table using a union with a row containing your measure.

A measure to get amount of the last two years:

`AmountLastTwo = SUMx(TOPN(2;'Table';'Table'[Year]);[Amount])`

`TOPN(2..` will make sure the measure always contain the last two years.

Then you can create a new table using `UNION` between your original table and a row containing the measure like this:

`UnionTable = UNION('Table'; ROW("Year";"LastTwoYears";"Amount";[AmountLastTwo]))`

```
Year            Amount
2010            10000
2011            12300
2012            14000
2013            13000
2014            22000
2015            10000
LastTwoYears    32000
```

You add a table from this button and then paste the code from above:

[image]

Another option is to do this in Power Query.

1. Duplicate your table and name it SUM_LAST_TWO
2. Sort by year and then select keep the top rows (using the UI)
3. Sum the amount (using the UI)
4. Create an empty query (new source > empty query) and add this to the formula field:`= #table({"Year", "Amount"}, {{"Last2Years",#"SUM_LAST_TWO"}})`. This will create a one-row table with the sum over the last two years.
5. In your originial table, append the one-row table you just created (using the UI)

However, if it is not really necessary to have this extra row (that breaks the data type) in your table I would recommend using only the measure `AmountLastTwo`.

Comment: Thanks. You are so great. I think there is mistyping in your answer. You write `AmountLastTwo = SUMx(TOPN(2;'Table';'Table'[Year]);[Amount])` two times but didn't add `Union` command in your answer

Comment: Can you add some images to your answer please? For first solution.

Comment: @Arian Ah sorry! Pasted the wrong code snippet. What more exactly do you want pictures of?

Comment: Thanks dear @Karl Anka. If it's possible picture from solution 1 steps.